# create new xml from existing xml after xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a bunch of xml files which I need to transform using XSLT. I have created the XSLT file and gave the reference of it in the original xml file header. I want to execute a script or a code may be in java/javascript so that either original xml file gets transformed to updated xml or a new modified xml file gets created.

Here are the files

product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="product-xsl.xsl" ?>
<products>
  <product>
    <sku>12854</sku>
    <productId>1051806941102</productId>
    <name>Manufacturer - Test sku - Color</name>
    <source>bestbuy</source>
    <type>HardGood</type>
    <startDate>2000-03-01</startDate>
    <new>false</new>
    <department>PHOTO/COMMODITIES</department>
 </product>
<products>
```

product-xsl.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<products>
<xsl:for-each select="products/product">
    <product>
            <sku><xsl:value-of select="sku"/></sku>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
            <department><xsl:value-of select="department"/></department>
    </product>
</xsl:for-each>
</products>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can see the updated XML while performing inspect element in firefox/safari but I want it in a new xml file or update existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is both a programming as well as a stylesheet language. Declaring it in the header of an XML file only styles the web rendering of XML file. To actually transform the XML file from original to final output, you would need to run both .xml and .xsl file using an XSLT processor.

Almost all the general purpose languages maintain XSLT processors including Java, PHP, Python, C#, VB, and still others. Below is a Java XML transformation:

```
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class XMLTransformation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {

            String xmlFile = "/Path/to/Original/XML/file.xml";
            String xslFile = "/Path/to/XSL/file.xml";

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(xslFile));
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

            Source text = new StreamSource(new File(xmlFile));
            transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("/Path/to/Output/XML/file.xml")));

    }
}
```

By the way, you do not need to run `xsl:for-each` in your XSLT. Simply use the identity transform to copy entire markup and then strip out the nodes not needed under `<products>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IdentityTransform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product/*[not(local-name()='sku' or
                                   local-name()='name' or
                                   local-name()='department')]">
<!-- ALTERNATIVE:  -->
<!-- <xsl:template match="productId|source|type|startDate|new">  -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I already implemented it using the similar kind of snippet but thanks for explanation it helped in better understanding.